# Loading quicklisp package for use in another lisp file

Tags: common-lisp, compile-time, sbcl, quicklisp, eval-when

I have downloaded a large software project [FriCAS](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/) which I have compiled from source and using SBCL.  This was just a matter of using GNU .configure - I am a complete Lisp newbie.

However, in order to add some further functionality I have - by very carefully following directions - installed quicklisp and a few extra packages.  So far so good.

Here's my issue: I am trying to compile an external lisp file for use in the system.  I need to make quicklisp and its packages visible to the compiler.  So I've copied my .sbclrc file to the top of my lisp file:

```
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))
```

I have followed this with

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (ql:quickload "f2cl-lib"))
```

I have already installed `f2cl-lib` with quicklisp.  However, my compiler (within FriCAS) immediately aborts with

```
; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;   
;     Package QL does not exist.
```

I'm a bit stumped here - there's probably something trivial and obvious which is missing, but as I say from a newbie perspective I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a FAQ. See also the documentation for [`eval-when`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_eval_w.htm#eval-when).

**The File Compiler**

Remember, a *file compiler* compiles forms and does not execute them. It just generates code for later execution. Generally. Though, in Common Lisp there are some exceptions to this rule: for example a *macro*, used in the source code, will be run by the *file compiler*. But Common Lisp also allows us to tell the *file compiler* to execute code at compile time, that's one of the use cases of `eval-when`.

**Your example simplified**

If you have a file:

```
(load "file-which-creates-package-foo")

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (foo:bar))
```

Then the *file compiler* will generate code for loading the file, but it will not load the file.

Next, the *file compiler* sees a second form, where the *file compiler* is instructed to execute a statement at *compile time* (and only at *compile time*), so `(foo:bar)` will be executed at compile time. But it is worse: Since the loading code has not been executed yet, the package `FOO` is unknown, and the form `(foo:bar)` will be read at *compile time*, the reader already complains at *compile time* that the package `FOO` does not exist.

**The use of EVAL-WHEN**

What you need to do, is to tell the *file compiler* to actually load the stuff it needs during compilation. The file already contains an [`eval-when`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_eval_w.htm#eval-when) form, so that should give you a hint: use `eval-when`. It has three *situations*:

- `:compile-toplevel`  -> the file compiler executes the enclosed forms
- `:load-toplevel`  -> the file compiler generates code so that the code will be executed when loading the code
- `:execute`

Make sure that those *situations* are mentioned, when the code should be executed.

**Possible solutions**

So there are possible solutions:

- as above, use `EVAL-WHEN` to be able to execute forms by the *file compiler*
- write the loading code into a separate file and compile/load this file before you use the package. One could also add this file to a *system* such that it will be loaded by the compiling the system, before the using code will be compiled.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reply - which I can mostly understand.  I'm getting the sense that Lisp is far far too difficult for an incompetent bungler like me; so I'll try for a bit more, then give up gracefully.

Comment: @Alasdair: it's possible to learn that and places like stackoverflow can help with the programming problems. FriCAS/Axiom is a really complex piece of software and extending its implementation makes some learning necessary. There is also a mailing list for FriCAS, where one may get more help extending it.

Comment: Oh yes - I've been making a huge nuisance of myself on the FriCAS mailing list!